# Data Driven Protractor With Excel

Tags: node.js, protractor, build-automation, file-conversion, data-driven

I have been working with protractor for a short while now and having checked the forums online currently there is no solution to have protractor run via excel for software builds in nodejs. 
Could anyone please advise as to when will this feature set be added to protractor?

I have a working solution so far feeding in a json file and iterating through it with lodash but have run into difficulty converting json to csv/Excel.
Worked through nodejs conversion packages such json2csv etc.. but to no avail returning the correct format of eg

```
TestName,Field1,Field2,Field3,Expecatation,RequiredField
```

From Json File eg.

```
"TestName1": [
    {
        "Field1": "Value1",
        "Field2": "Value2",
        "Field3": "Value3",
        "Expectation": {
            "RequiredField": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "Field1": "Value1",
        "Field2": "Value2",
        "Field3": "Value3",
        "Expectation": {
            "RequiredField": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks